# JavaScript firing on page load instead of event (Bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm having the strangest issue when I'm calling in functions on an event. I'm trying to get a function to run when the window is resized using `$(window).resize()` but it seems to fire the function as soon as the DOM loads then never again.

I'm probably missing something really simple here but I've been looking at it all day and I need a bit of outside help.

I've created a watered down version on JSfiddle that does the same thing but using `$('a').click()` instead of `$(window).resize()` so it's a bit easier to test. As the same issue is cropping up I have a feeling there's something wrong with my function but I just can't see it.

Link is here http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/APLZ2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the function and sending it's output into the jQuery thingy as a parameter:

```
$('a').click(alert('hello'), imageResizer());
```

instead, try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {alert('hello');  imageResizer(); });
```

This provides an anonyomous function, which will be run when the item is clicked, calling imageResizer(), whereas the way you had it, it ran the imageResizer() function and put it's return value into the onclick handler. The reason it didn't work later on was because it would have been treating whatever the return value of the imageResizer() function was as code that it was trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
}, imageResizer());​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the event instead of assigning an handler to it

```
$('a').click(alert('hello'), imageResizer());​
```

Should be

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // I suppose you will want that ... it will avoid your window jumping to the top when you click due to the href="#"
   alert('hello');
   imageResizer();
});​
```

Comment: Haha yes, yes I was :(

I knew it would be something daft. I think I need to take a break lol. Thanks for this.